# Citation not working. Colon (":") in label / citation key causes a problem. Worked before

Tags: citing, cite-package

My previous paper uses this citation style: `\cite{watson:1992}`.  (there is a colon inside the key).

Now, I move this paper's latex code into a new file, and the above format is not working anymore. The problem is that if I use a source that doesn't involve a `:` (colon) (eg, `\cite{watson1992}`), then it is **working**.

Now, I can't go and change anything key with `:` inside the `\cite{ . }`. It is too much work!

What shall I do?

Comment: I do not understand how this can happen. Anyway, can't you use the "search and replace" functionality of your text editor? I do not expect that you have many ":" in other places in your bib file.

Comment: Question/brainstorming for others: Can the encoding of the file play a role? I would suspect no since ":" is an ASCII character.

Comment: In general, calling for "help" is ok but without providing the necessary information it is difficult to do. Can you explain the setting you use (bibtex vs. biblatex, overleaf vs. MiKTeX vs TeXLive)?

Comment: Ideally, you can reproduce the problem using a template from https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/.

Comment: Please tell us if you use the `babel` package with a language (e.g, `french`) that makes the `:` ("colon") active in TeX jargon.

Comment: Please tell us if you use the `babel` package with a language (e.g, `french`) that makes the `:` (colon) character "active" in TeX jargon.

Comment: "Normally", colons should work fine in cite keys. Colons (as well as some other special characters like `"`) can be problematic, because they might be turned into active characters, but many cite commands guard against such a case and would still work. We need an example of your specific problem in order to say anything other than "avoid colons" (which you don't want). Please show us a small example document starting with `\documentclass` along with a small preamble and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that reproduces the issue with as little code as possible.